# troubles re-installing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I had  **RVM** and **RBENV** installed on my computer and I decided to keep only **RBENV** So I followed this [setup](https://github.com/lewagon/setup/blob/master/macOS.md#installing-ruby-with-rbenv)
*I am on mac with high sierra*

- The first trouble I am facing is that `ruby -v` displays nothing.
  I know that my ruby version is ok because of ohmyzsh `[2.4.4]`
- When I try to run this command `gem install rake bundler rspec rubocop pry pry-byebug hub colored octokit`nothing happens... I can't install bundler nor rails.... I am not supposed to use the sudo... What could be wrong and how could I find fix this? 
  I can't even launch `irb` and `gem install bundler`does nothing

there must be a conflict somewhere?

I ran this [dignostic](http://curl%20https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ssaunier/056a755214f4109760ca306c14dd569f/raw/wagon_diagnostic.sh%20%7C%20sh):

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   320  100   320    0     0    858      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   860
--- PATH ---
./bin:/Users/bill/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/sbin
--- RBENV ---
rbenv is /usr/local/opt/rbenv/bin/rbenv
rbenv is /usr/local/bin/rbenv
  system
* 2.4.4 (set by /Users/bill/.rbenv/version)
--- RUBY ---
ruby is /Users/bill/.rbenv/shims/ruby
ruby is /usr/bin/ruby
ruby is /usr/local/bin/ruby
--- GEM ---
gem is /Users/bill/.rbenv/shims/gem
gem is /usr/bin/gem
gem is /usr/local/bin/gem
--- POSTGRES ---
postgres is /usr/local/bin/postgres
postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.5
2018-09-11 17:04:51.406 CEST [30591] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2018-09-11 17:04:51.406 CEST [30591] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.6, which is not compatible with this version 10.5.
```

See my .zshrc

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# You can change the theme with another one:
#   https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Add ruby version on prompt (float right)
if [ -x "$(command -v rbenv)" ]; then RPS1='[$(ruby_prompt_info)]$EPS1'; fi

# Useful plugins for Rails development with Sublime Text
plugins=(gitfast brew rbenv last-working-dir common-aliases sublime zsh-syntax-highlighting history-substring-search)

# Prevent Homebrew from reporting - https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Analytics.md
export HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1

# Actually load Oh-My-Zsh
source "${ZSH}/oh-my-zsh.sh"

# Rails and Ruby uses the local `bin` folder to store binstubs.
# So instead of running `bin/rails` like the doc says, just run `rails`
export PATH="./bin:${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin"

# Store your own aliases in the ~/.aliases file and load the here.
[[ -f "$HOME/.aliases" ]] && source "$HOME/.aliases"

# Encoding stuff for the terminal
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Also ran this [diganostic](http://curl%20-fsSL%20https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor%20%7C%20bash):

```
  You seem to have multiple rbenv installs in the following locations.
  Please pick just one installation and remove the others.

  /usr/local/opt/rbenv/bin/rbenv
  /usr/local/bin/rbenv

Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20180822)
Counting installed Ruby versions: 1 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: %
```

here is a screenshot of my `~`maybe something needs to be removed ? what about that `.rvmrc` it says `rvm_auto_reload_flag=1
rvm_auto_reload_flag=2`
[image]

#### EDIT

I am opening the folders and files:
in `.profile`it says:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**Clarify the "nothing  happens"**

```
  ~ gem install rake bundler rspec rubocop pry pry-byebug hub colored octokit

➜  ~
```

Comment: There's a lot here going on here, but a couple of pointers. The first step in the [setup](https://github.com/lewagon/setup/blob/master/macOS.md#installing-ruby-with-rbenv) you linked to covers removing existing rbenv installations and should help with the "You seem to have multiple rbenv installs". Don't worry about `.profile` - I could be wrong on this, but I don't think that file gets used by zsh. Lastly, please clarify the "nothing happens".

Comment: I removed the rbenv and rvm installation
Nothing happens, usually when I install gem , there are traces of the installation, here it just seems to skip the command `gem install ...`

Comment: I edited my question  see at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with:

- `brew update`
- `brew upgrade`
- `brew uninstall ruby`